# filling an array of numbers in assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm

I wrote the following code in order to fill an array with the numeric strings `9876..1234`:

```
segment     .data
  counter   dd 9877
  count     dd 8642
  array     times 9876 dd '0000' 

segment     .bss
  buffer    resb  4 

segment     .text
  global    _start

  _start: 

  mov ecx, [count]

  mov edx, array
  mov dword [pointer], array 

  l1:
    push ecx
    push edx

    dec dword [counter]                      ; decrease the counter
    lea esi, [buffer]
    mov eax, [counter]
    call int_to_string

    mov ecx, eax ; "begin print" position
    xor edx, edx
getlen:
    cmp byte [ecx + edx], 10
    jz gotlen
    inc edx
    jmp getlen
gotlen:
    inc edx

    push eax                             ; printing the string converted
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    int 0x80
    pop eax                              ; printing the string converted


    pop edx                              ; copying the string to array
    mov [edx], eax
    add edx, 4

    pop ecx
  loop l1


  mov ecx, [count]                  ;printing the array
  mov eax, array
  l2:
    push ecx

    mov [pointer], eax
    push eax

    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, pointer
    mov edx, 4
    int 0x80

    pop eax
    add eax, 4

    pop ecx
  loop l2

  mov   eax, 1
  mov   ebx, 0
  int   0x80

int_to_string:
  add   esi, 9 ; counter + 9 ?
  mov   byte [esi], 10
  mov   ebx, 10         

.next_digit:
  xor   edx, edx        
  div   ebx             
  add   dl, '0'          
  dec   esi             
  mov   [esi],dl
  test  eax, eax            
  jnz   .next_digit
  mov   eax, esi
  ret
```

Printing out causes random characters to be printed on the screen. What would cause this in my code?

Comment: You've got two loops that both appear to be writing to stdout. Which of them is causing the incorrect printouts? What is `pointer`? I don't see it being declared anywhere in your code. Also, one obvious problem is that you're only reserving 4 bytes of space for `buffer`. As I wrote when I posted that `int_to_string` function in some of my previous answers, the buffer that `esi` points to is expected to have room for at least 10 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three central errors:

1) "buffer" is too small & pointer is missing.

Change

```
segment     .bss
  buffer    resb  4
```

to

```
segment     .bss
  buffer    resb  10
  pointer   resd 1
```

2) "copying" is wrong.

Change

```
pop eax                              ; printing the string converted


pop edx                              ; copying the string to array
mov [edx], eax
add edx, 4
```

to

```
pop eax                              ; printing the string converted

mov eax, [eax]
pop edx                              ; copying the string to array
mov [edx], eax
add edx, 4
```

3) "printing" is wrong.

Change

```
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, pointer
mov edx, 4
int 0x80
```

to

```
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, [pointer]
mov edx, 4
int 0x80
```